# Monodroid pass int[] in Intent

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, mono, xamarin.android

I have two activity A, and B. I start activity B from activity A, like this:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof (BActivity));
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

If you press a button on activity B, i have to pass an int[] array to activity A, i created a test code which does this:

```
var intent = new Intent();
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
intent.PutExtra("__extra__", array);
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
Finish();
```

But whenever I try to get this value from the intent, i receiving null. Here is how i tried:

```
var value = data.GetIntArrayExtra("__extra__");
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried the same with string, and it worked, it seems to me, that just the int array is not working...

Comment: It's weird. I tried exactly the same thing and I can get data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try it as :

```
Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
bdl.PutIntArray("__extra__",array);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.PutExtra("extra", bdl);
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
Finish();
```

and on `OnActivityResult` :

```
Bundle credBdl = data.GetBundleExtra("extra");
int[] array=credBdl.GetIntArray("__extra__");
```

Comment: It is still not working... I'm getting the Bundle correctly, but when i call credBdl.GetIntArray it still returning null.